# Admin Grid Erratic Edit Form Behavior

Tags: module, edit, action

My custom module uses an Admin Grid to display my model. I have added a link to my edit method with a button as follows:

```
$this->addColumn('action',
    array(
        'header' => 'Action',
        'width' => '50px',
        'type' => 'action',
        'getter' => 'getId',
        'actions' => array(
            array(
                'caption' => 'Edit',
                'url' => array(
                'base'=>'*/*/edit'
            ),
            'field' => 'store_id'
        )
    ),
    'filter' => false,
    'sortable' => false,
)
);
```

Nine times out of 10 this works correctly and loads my Edit form with pre-filled data. However one on 10 clicks will load an empty form. This is because the link on the edit button is using `id` instead of `store_id`.

I’ve tried playing around with the ID’s on the `addColumn()` method about but it seems futile this the error is erratic. Even when a link is incorrectly constructed for a row, the other rows will be correct. Further it’s not the same row(s) that experience this behavior.

Really not sure hat else to try.

Bob.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this issue, hopefully the solution may help others who might experience this.

My getRowUrl method was the cause of the issue, I was using the incorrect paramater 'id' instead of 'store_id':

```
public function getRowUrl($row) {
         return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('store_id' => $row->getId()));
}
```

Obvious in hindsight but easy to over-look.